# Matching classes (from reflection) by inheritance on Scala

Tags: scala, inheritance, reflection, match, scala-2.10

I'm working with Scala 2.10, and I have a situation on which I have a sequence of classes which I loaded from reflection, something like this:

```
val names = Seq("Foo", "Bar", "Baz")
val classes = names map Class.forName
```

(In the real problem I have several classes loaded recursively from a directory.)

And let's say the hierarchy looks something like this:

```
class A
class B
class C
trait D

class Foo extends A
class Bar extends B
class Baz extends C with D
```

I'm pretty aware of type erasure, so I don't know which way should I take now. Since `classes` would be of type `Seq[Class[_ <: Any]]` now, what could I do to match the classes, including from subtying?

For example, I'd like to do something like this:

```
classes match { i =>
  case /* A */ => println("i inherits from A") // should match Foo
  case /* B */ => println("i inherits from B") // should match Bar 
  case /* D */ => println("i has D trait") // should match Baz
};
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Class.isAssignableFrom`. For example:

```
val some = classOf[Some[_]] // subclass
val option = classOf[Option[_]] // superclass
val product = classOf[Product] // trait
option.isAssignableFrom(some) // true, because Some is subclass of Option
some.isAssignableFrom(option) // false, because Option is the superclass
product.isAssignableFrom(some) // true, because Some implements Product
```

You can even create a custom extractor for use in a `match`:

```
class ClassMatcher(clazz: Class[_]) {
  def unapply(clazz2: Class[_]) = clazz.isAssignableFrom(clazz2)
}

object OptionSubType extends ClassMatcher(classOf[Option[_]])

classOf[Some[_]] match {
  case OptionSubType() => println("Some is a subtype of Option")
}
```

Comment: Do you know any way that I could use to match them by type, like `case x: Foo` or `case x: Class[Foo]`? I'd like to write a bit more idiomatic code, not sure if a lot of `if`-statements would be that nice (I might need to check against a lot of classes). Perhaps some way to make a syntatic sugar for this?